# Warning while saving opportunity in OpenERP

Tags: python, odoo

After creating an opportunity, when I click on save, it gives me this warning for some users:

> "Operation prohibited by access rules, or performed on an already deleted document (Operation: read, Document type: User Modification)."

What's causing this problem?

**Update:** I have created a new user of admin type and I added these groups:
Sales/User,Sales/User All Leads,Survey/User,Tools/User. It gives me a warning while creating an opportunity.

I added the following groups to the new user and it's working fine: Employee, PartnerManager, Marketing/User, Accounting/Accountant, Accounting/Invoice, Accounting/Manager, Administration/Access Rights, Human Resource/Manager, Human Resource/User, Knowledge/User, Marketing/Manager, Project/Manager, Sales/Manager, Tools/Manager, trimax/AdminMeeting, Trimax/‌​SalesExecutive, Trimax/Vertical, Trimax/SalesHead, Trimax/SalesManager, Useability/An‌alyticAccounting, Useability/Extended, View, Useability/MultiCompanies, Useability/No One, Useability/Product Uos View, Useability/Product Variant, Warehouse/Manager, Warehouse/User, Tools/User, Administration/Configuration

But in already created user if I remove the above groups which give warning ,then also it shows same warning.

The solution I mentioned above was for new users,but for some existing users it was still giving problem. So I removed some unwanted groups, which I didn't needed for those users and it worked, now it does not show warning. Was the warning due to some access right overlap or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Those users probably don't have access rights for the opportunity object, or some child object. Read the [access rights documentation](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/book/8/8_20_Config/8_20_Config_accessRights.html) for more details.

**Update:** You said that you're having trouble configuring a new user. As an experiment, try adding permissions to an existing user instead of starting a brand new user. Also, check that you've configured the roles as well as the permissions, that trips me up sometimes.

**Another Update:** You said that removing some groups stopped the warning. It may be that you have removed all access rules from the object. If no groups are explicitly granted access to something in OpenERP, then everyone is granted access. If you really want to figure out what's going on, I suggest you read the documentation I linked to above. You can also search for the error message in the source code and see exactly what it is complaining about. I find it really helpful to run the OpenERP server in debug mode, and step through the code when I'm trying to understand some weird behaviour like this. You can also try and figure out exactly which change triggers this error by adding and removing groups until you find a single change that makes the problem happen.

Comment: I have created new user of admin type and when I add these groups :Sales/User,Sales/User All Leads,Survey/User,Tools/User .It gives warning while creating opportunity.

Comment: I have added following groups to user and Its working fine:Employee,PartnerManager,Marketing/User,Accounting/Accountant,
Accounting/Invoice,Accounting/Manager,Administration/Access Rights,
Human Resource/Manager,Human Resource/User,Knowledge/User,Marketing /Manager,Project/Manager,Sales/Manager,Tools/Manager,trimax/AdminMeeting,Trimax/SalesExecutive,Trimax/Vertical,Trimax/SalesHead,Trimax/SalesManager,Useability/AnalyticAccounting,Useability/Extended,View,Useability

Comment: /MultiCompanies,Useability/No One,Useability/Product Uos View,Useability/Product Varient,Warehouse/Manager,Warehouse/User,Tools/User,Administration/Configuration

Comment: But in already created user if I  remove the above groups which give warning ,then also it shows same warning.

Comment: It's hard for me to understand all that stuff in comments. It might be better to add that kind of detail to your original question and then just add a comment here that you've updated the question. I've added a couple more suggestions to my answer that might help you find the solution.

Comment: The solution I mentioned above was for new users,but for some existing users it was still giving problem.So I removed some unwanted groups,which I didn't needed for those users and it worked, now it does not show warning.Was the warning due to some access right overlap or something else?

Comment: Sorry, @Sameer, I don't know exactly what's happening in your system. I moved the details from your comments into the question, so maybe someone else will be able to help you better. I also added some hints to my answer to help you solve the problem yourself. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Hi these is due to the access right problem .So you give the proper access right to your user(for creating the oppurtunity)

Answer (score 0):

same problem here.I'm using Multi-company, I provid all permistion to the user