# Warning ! while saving opportunity

Tags: odoo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Warning while saving opportunity,in OpenERP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7874752/warning-while-saving-opportunity-in-openerp)

After creating opportunity when I try to save it,I get this warning for some users----

"Operation prohibited by access rules, or performed on an already deleted document (Operation: read, Document type: User Modification)."

Although the opportunity gets saved but initially it gives this warning.This warning I think is due to some access rights problem, however I am giving all the access to these users.Please can anyone help me on this.

Thanks
Sameer

Comment: Instead of asking the same question three times, Sameer, try improving your original question. Add a screenshot, point to some code, tell us what you've already tried.

Answer (score 6):

You should check the access rights for "res.users" for the user you logged in.

Comment: I have provided these users all the access rights as in admin just leaving horizontal ones.